# Calculating the time left for a countdown timer with a function vs just a variable

Tags: javascript, function, date

I'm wondering about the difference between the two. Is there any impact on performance for example and are there any subtle differences?

This will happen every second for a countdown timer

`const timeLeft = endTime - new Date().getTime()`

vs.

`const timeLeft = () => endTime - new Date().getTime()`

Comment: The second one declares a function but doesn't call it so you won't get a value back and creating a new anonymous function that you'll never call every second is not only bad for performance but not useful. Also, you don't need to create a `new Date` on every call, just use `Date.now()`

Comment: Thnks!! That is great a tip especially regarding the date class. I am later on in my code using the timeLeft function (and the variable). Would this change anything

Comment: If you declare the function outside of the `setInterval` so that you're not creating a new function every tick, then it could be useful. A cheaper solution would be call `timeLeft` once when you first start your timer, and then increment a counter on each tick.